# Grails Repo Down?

Tags: grails, artifactory

It seems like the Grails repo might be down (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core). Myself and two other co-workers have tried reaching it, but the HTTP response just hangs. Maybe it has moved and we have the wrong link? This is causing some issues with our build-dependencies that rely on this repo.

Thanks!

- Eddie

Comment: You can keep an eye on the status at https://status.jfrog.io/.

Comment: The issues have come and gone at least a couple times today.  At the moment the service is operational.

Answer (score 1):

> Grails Repo Down?

Yes, it is.  We are working on it.

> Maybe it has moved and we have the wrong link?

No, we have not moved it.

Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: It looks like it's back up; thank you!